# Return based on instanceof of exceptions

Tags: java, exception, return

I have a task to return an boolean based instanceof of exceptions

If an exception is an instance of `ConnectTimeoutException` then return  true or if an exception instance is of `SocketTimeoutException` then return as true.

I have written the code, is this the correct way to do it?

(Note: I have to check this in return statement and not in if statement.)

Code:

```
public boolean canRetry(RetryContext context) {

        Throwable exception = context.getLastThrowable();
        ......
        ......
        ......
        ......
        ......
        // Some Code
        return (exception instanceof ConnectTimeoutException || exception instanceof SocketTimeoutException);


    }
```

Comment: Somehow this does not make sense. You return "its instance" in any case, so why not just `return exception;`? What are you trying to achieve/to solve? Why can't you use `if`? Completely unclear.

Comment: It will return `boolean`.

Comment: Why playing around with instances, why not simple throw e ? and check for instance in upper layer or just catch it and do whatever you want ?

Comment: `return (exception instanceof ConnectTimeoutException || exception instanceof SocketTimeoutException);` looks fine for me in this case.

Comment: @lexicore Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

The way you currently have it done would return you a boolean true if `exception` was an instance of either of the classes otherwise it would return a boolean false. You are looking for something like this:

```
if(exception instanceof ConnectTimeoutException || exception instanceof SocketTimeoutException){
    return exception;
}
```